# How to write a square bracket in prolog?

Tags: prolog, grammar, context-free-grammar, dcg

This may sound strange, but it is used in a parser, I want to be able to parse something of the form

> foo[bar]

So this would be represented in a list as:

> [foo, [, bar, []
>   Maybe such a word would be written in DCG as:

```
x --> id [[] arg []]
```

The problem is that the square bracket is a reserved character, so how can I represent this in prolog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not treat your square brackets as atoms (i.e., `'['` and `']'`), along with everything else?

How about, for **example**:

```
label1(T) --> id(X), label2(Y), {T =.. [X, Y]}.
label2(Y) --> ['['], innerexp(Y), [']'].
id(X) --> [X].
innerexp(Y) --> [Y].
```

Execution:

```
?- phrase(label1(T), [foo, '[', bar, ']'], Rem).
T = foo(bar),
Rem = [].
```

Comment: how would I read in square brackets from a file and put them in single commas?

Answer (score 0):

Does `"["` (in quotes) do the trick?

Comment: Ah well. I can't think of anything else, sorry.